# Read from keycloak protocol mapper attribute that was set with OAuth2AuthorizeRequest

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, keycloak

In order to get token I use below code

```
  OAuth2AuthorizeRequest oAuth2AuthorizeRequest = OAuth2AuthorizeRequest
                    .withClientRegistrationId(clientRegistration.getRegistrationId())
                    .attributes(attr->attr.put("scope", "cccc"))
                    .principal(PRINCIPAL_NAME)
                    .build();

  OAuth2AuthorizedClient client = oAuth2AuthorizedClientManager.authorize(oAuth2AuthorizeRequest);

  return client.getAccessToken().getTokenValue();
```

Can I access attr.put("scope", "cccc") inside a custom keycloak protocol mapper that has the below signature?

```
  @Override
  public AccessToken transformAccessToken(AccessToken token, ProtocolMapperModel mappingModel, KeycloakSession session,
      UserSessionModel userSession,
      ClientSessionContext clientSessionCtx) {}
```

Comment: Can you please provide more information, including dependencies/versions and your configuration? Are you using the keycloak adapter (see [update](https://www.keycloak.org/2023/03/adapter-deprecation-update.html)) which does not support the latest generation of Spring?

Comment: spring.boot.version = 3.2.1, spring-security.version = 6.2.1 and keycloak.version = 22.0.5. No, I do not use keycloak adapter